# Need help iterating through a class to update scores in a JS true or false game

Tags: javascript, iteration

I'm building a true or false game in JavaScript and the scoring works by changing each of the 10 score elements either green or red for a correct or incorrect answer.  These score elements are divs all sharing a class of 'score-elements'.  The issue I'm having while trying to iterate through each of the elements with each question is, all of the elements will change either red or green, instead of just the relevant one for question 1, question 2 etc.

I have attached the GitHub link for anyone who can take a look.

Many thanks in advance!

[text](https://github.com/ShieldsJohn/aye_or_naw)

.....................

Comment: Please do not post links to your code. Post the relevant portions of your code right here in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this blindly, but here lies the problem:

```
function checkAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = questionsAnswers[questionIndex];
    const correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;
    console.log(correctAnswer)
    const scoreBar = document.getElementsByClassName("score-elements");
    Array = [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, score9, score10];
    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        for (var i = 0; i < scoreBar.length; i++) {
            console.log(scoreBar[i]);
            scoreBar[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
         }
        /**document.getElementById("score1").style.backgroundColor = "green";**/
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < scoreBar.length; i++) {
            console.log(scoreBar[i]);
            scoreBar[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
        /**document.getElementById("score1").style.backgroundColor = "red";**/
    }
    questionIndex++;
    loadQuestion();
}
```

You don't need to loop through all `scoreBar` items, because there are as many of those as answers. So it's enough to use `questionIndex` to tell which element in `scoreBar` you need to change the styling of.

```
function checkAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = questionsAnswers[questionIndex];
    const correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;
    console.log(correctAnswer)
    const scoreBar = document.getElementsByClassName("score-elements");

    // CHANGES
    const color = (userAnswer === correctAnswer) ? 'green' : 'red';

    scoreBar[questionIndex].style.backgroundcolor = color;
    // END: CHANGES

    questionIndex++;
    loadQuestion();
}
```

```js
//question and answer array
const questionsAnswers = [
    {
        question: "Dundee was a former capital of Scotland - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "naw",
    },
    {
        question: "Gorillas usually eat more than 15kg of food per day - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "aye",
    },
    {
        question: "K2 is the second highest mountain in the world - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "aye",
    },
    {
        question: "Irn-Bru was first created in Edinburgh - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "naw",
    },
    {
        question: "The song ‘(Everything I Do) I Do It For You’ by Bryan Adams is the UK’s longest running number one single - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "aye",
    },
    {
        question: "North America is the fourth largest continent in the world - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "naw",
    },
    {
        question: "Sir Chris Hoy has won six Olympic gold medals in track cylcing - Ayr or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "aye",
    },
    {
        question: "PDF stands for Personal Document Format - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "naw",
    },
    {
        question: "The London Underground has more stations than the Paris Metro - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "naw",
    },
    {
        question: "The planet Pluto is smaller than the moon - Aye or Naw?",
        correctAnswer: "aye",
    },
];
let questionIndex = 0;
let userAnswer;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "button") {
            }
        })
    }
    runGame();
});
function runGame() {
    let plrName = document.getElementById("pname");
    let playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    document.getElementById("game-area").style.display = "none";
    plrName.addEventListener("input", () => {
        if (plrName.value.length === 3) {
            playButton.style.display = "none";
            startGame();
        } else {
            playButton.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
    const aye = document.getElementById("aye-button");
    const naw = document.getElementById("naw-button");
    aye.addEventListener("click", () => {
        userAnswer = "aye"; 
        checkAnswer();
    });
    naw.addEventListener("click", () => {
        userAnswer = "naw";
        checkAnswer();
    });
}
function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("game-area").style.display = "block";
    loadQuestion();
}
function loadQuestion() {
    const currentQuestion = questionsAnswers[questionIndex];
    document.getElementById("question-box").innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
}
function checkAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = questionsAnswers[questionIndex];
    const correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;
    console.log(correctAnswer)
    const scoreBar = document.getElementsByClassName("score-elements");
    Array = [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, score9, score10];
    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        for (var i = 0; i < scoreBar.length; i++) {
            console.log(scoreBar[i]);
            scoreBar[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
         }
        /**document.getElementById("score1").style.backgroundColor = "green";**/
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < scoreBar.length; i++) {
            console.log(scoreBar[i]);
            scoreBar[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
        /**document.getElementById("score1").style.backgroundColor = "red";**/
    }
    questionIndex++;
    loadQuestion();
}
//increment to 10, displaying correct answers as green and incorrect as red in the score-bar
function updateScore() {
}
//once all ten questions have been answered the player is told if won or lost and invited to play again
function endGame() {
}
```